# PDO Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Returns me an error 
Here is my code

I think the problem is at 'ilosc_znakow'.

And I don't know why.
I try add  PDO::PARAM_INT but its don't help

```php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO zlecenia (id_klienta, nazwa, adres_url, ilosc_znakow, frazy_kluczowe, uwagi, dead_line, status) 
VALUES (:id_klienta, :nazwa, :adres_url, :ilosc_znakow, :frazy_kluczowe, :uwagi, :dead_line, :status)");
$stmt->bindParam(':id_klienta', $id_klienta);
$stmt->bindParam(':nazwa', $nazwa);
$stmt->bindParam(':adres_url', $adres_url);
$stmt->bindParam(':ilosc_znakow', $ilosc_znakow, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':frazy_kluczowe', $frazy_kluczowe);
$stmt->bindParam(':uwagi', $uwagi);
$stmt->bindParam(':dead_line', $dead_line);

// insert a row
$rawdate = htmlentities($_POST['dead_line']);
$dead_line = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rawdate));
$id_klienta = $_POST['id_klienta'];
$nazwa = $_POST['nazwa'];
$adres_url = $_POST['adres_url'];
$ilosc_znakow = $_POST['ilosc_znakow'];
$frazy_kluczowe = $_POST['frazy_kluczowe'];
$uwagi = $_POST['uwagi'];
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You never did bind `:status`

Answer (score 0):

You're setting :status, but you never set the value, just add next code where you set the values of the parameters :
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $status);